# Adding .cer file with public key to .NET Core 2 with Sustainsys

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, saml-2.0, adfs, sustainsys-saml2

I have a .cer file which includes the public key that I need in order to test authentication against AD FS.
I can easily add it in the MVC sample in Web.config (setting signingCertificate fileName) existing in the solution and it seems to work but I can't find any way to add in the AspNetCore2 project.

The closest I've found is the SigningServiceCertificate but that only has a getter and I've read in another thread that it's supposedly to add the public key to the SigningKeys collection somehow, I just can't figure it out how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking however I use Sustainsys with a certificate and I use the following line:

`var idp = new Sustainsys.Saml2.IdentityProvider(new entityId("https://sso.acme.com"), opt.SPOptions) { ... insert properties ... }`

`idp.SigningKeys.AddConfiguredKey(new X509Certificate2("customer-certificate.cer"));`

`opt.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(EncryptionHelper.GetX509Certificate2("INSERT-THUMBPRINT-OF-YOUR-CERTIFICATE"));`

Where `EncryptionHelper.GetX509Certificate2` is a custom helper I've written to read my certificate.

Here is the code for `EncryptionHelper` - I produced it on the back of one of the many examples online.

```
public static X509Certificate2 GetX509Certificate2(string thumbprint)
{
    X509Certificate2 retVal = null;

    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    var certCollection = store.Certificates;

    var signingCert = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);

    if (signingCert.Count > 0)
    {
        retVal = signingCert[0];
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Note that if you are running this in Azure then you also need to add the Thumbprint to Application Settings using these instructions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-ssl-cert-load

You can find the thumbprint as per these instructions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-retrieve-the-thumbprint-of-a-certificate

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I need. I did configure my IdP and added the AddConfiguredKey part but I wasn't aware that I need to read the certificate using the thumbprint as in the MVC sample this wasn't required - referencing the path to the .cer file was just enough. Could you please explain how would I do that? Do I need to actually install the certificate in order to get that thumbprint?

Comment: So I just installed the certificate and I can see the thumbprint value in hex format. Do I need to convert it to decimal and use it in order to get the certificate and add it to ServiceCertificates?

Comment: I figured there's no need for conversion and I just have to use that value without the blank spaces between the characters but now I receive a "Provided certificate is not valid because it does not contain a private key."
  

So I use something like this:
  

`var certCollection = store.Certificates;`
`var signingCert = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "INSERT-THUMBPRINT-OF-YOUR-CERTIFICATE", false);`

`return signingCert[0]`

Comment: Hmm, managed to create a private certificate, install it and add it to the ServiceCertificates through the thumbprint, although I have no idea what I'm missing since I don't get prompted a login pop-up/page.

Comment: I've updated my original response with some more information. If this doesn't help please provide more detail on the errors you are experiencing and how your application is configured. If my answer helps, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for providing the helper method and taking the time to answer. I am unsure whether I need a private certificate though (won't a public one be just enough?).   I only want to implement a simple Sign-in/Sign-out mechanism against AD FS within our application. The login pop-up does show up after all when I restart the browser and I can login. I'm curious why would one need to add a private certificate?

Comment: @gh0st1596 - you need to provide much clearer detail as to what the issue is as it is unclear from your description.  Code extracts (likely from startup.cs) showing how the authentication is working for a start.

Comment: here is the the piece of code that takes care of the configuration, in startup.cs I have this configured:

`options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("[ADFS-ENDPOINT-URL]");
options.IdentityProviders.Add(
    new IdentityProvider(
        new EntityId("[FEDERATiON-SERVICE-URL]/adfs/services/trust"), options.SPOptions)
            {
                MetadataLocation = "[METADATA-URL]",
                LoadMetadata = true,
                SingleSignOnServiceUrl = new Uri("[FS-URL]/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon", UriKind.Absolute)
            });`

Comment: And then simply add the public .cer file as you mentioned (sorry, character limited in the last message to add this part). Also, for the love of God, I can't figure it out how to properly format code in here, apologies.

    The problem is that I don't have any idea how to read the claims in .NET Core and can't find any leads or examples on this.

Comment: @gh0st1596 - sorry, but you don't provide enough clarity on the issue, steps to reproduce or errors you are experiencing to provide any further assistance.